# Add ASCII values of 2 char variables

Tags: java, ascii

I have just started to learn Java on my own, but I am stuck with this so could you explain me a bit more about how this works? Here is the exercise:

> In this exercise, Ze will ask you for the number of *Zomatoes* and
>   *Zinions* you want to buy.
>
> You have to enter an ASCII character in the range `[A-Za-z]` for both.
>   The number of Zomatoes you want to buy will be given to you in a
>   variable called `zomatoes`, which is of type `char`.
>
> The number of `Zinions` you want to buy will be given to you in a
>   variable called `zinions`, which is also of type `char`.
>
> You have to add the ASCII values of both the char variables (zomatoes
>   and zinions) and populate the variable called `items`, which is of
>   type `int`, with the sum.
>
> For example if you asked for `a` Zomatoes and `C` Zinions, the total
>   number of items is `a(97) + C(67)` = 164

This is the code they give me:

```
public class CrazyConverter { 

    public static void main(String args[]) {         
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Hello I am your friendly grocer Darth: "); 
        System.out.println("How many zomatoes do you want ? (Enter a character in the range [A-Za-z]): "); 
        String sZomatoes = scanner.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("How many zinions do you want ? (Enter a character in the range [A-Za-z]): "); 
        String sZinions = scanner.nextLine(); 

        char zomatoes = sZomatoes.charAt(0); 
        char zinions = sZinions.charAt(0); 
        int  items = 0; 
        sZomatoes= 65;
        ///{ 

   char zinions=(char) asciiValue;

                //start your coding here  

                //end

        ///} 

        System.out.println("Thank you ! you have asked for " + items + " items"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I could explain what the code is doing, but do you even know what the code is doing?  If not, anyone showing you any answers serves no learning purpose.  Learning on your own is a good thing, so try to learn what the current code is doing, even edit your question with your explanation as to what the code is doing and explain what is wrong.  You've already explained what you want it to do, so after explaining what is wrong with the current code, you may end up answering your own problem or we may help you after that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a homework.

```
     char zomatoes = sZomatoes.charAt(0);//storing character for zomatoes 
     char zinions = sZinions.charAt(0); //storing character for zinions
     int  items = zomatoes+zinions;//Adding the ascii value of both zomatoes and zinions.
```

I have already given you the hint.Hope you can correct the errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `char`(s) together and intialize `items`. I think you wanted something like,

```
char zomatoes = sZomatoes.charAt(0);
char zinions = sZinions.charAt(0);
int items = zomatoes + zinions;
System.out.printf("The total number of items is '%s'(%d) + '%s'(%d) = %d%n",
        zomatoes, (int) zomatoes, zinions, (int) zinions, items);
```

And when I run it with your sample input

```
Hello I am your friendly grocer Darth: 
How many zomatoes do you want ? (Enter a character in the range [A-Za-z]): 
a
How many zinions do you want ? (Enter a character in the range [A-Za-z]): 
C
The total number of items is 'a'(97) + 'C'(67) = 164
```